# Undefine factory on custom module

Tags: factory, sphinx, undefine

I am using Sphinx Search Extension. it was working good on Magento 2.2.8 version.
Now am upgrade my store on 2.3.2 it give error

> Undefined factory sphinx

Anyone also face this issue? if then how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how sphinx works, but your search engine requires a factory attached to the `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\ItemCollectionProvider` class.
You can do this via `di.xml` of one of your modules (probably the sphinx module itself)

```
<type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\ItemCollectionProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="factories" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sphinx" xsi:type="object">class name or virtual type name here</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Here is an example on how it works for elasticsearch6.
`vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch-6/etc/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\ItemCollectionProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="factories" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="elasticsearch6" xsi:type="object">elasticsearchAdvancedCollectionFactory</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

where `elasticsearchAdvancedCollectionFactory` is a virtual type defined in `vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/etc/di.xml`

```
 <virtualType name="elasticsearchAdvancedCollectionFactory" type="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Advanced\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="instanceName" xsi:type="string">elasticsearchAdvancedCollection</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

where `elasticsearchAdvancedCollection` is another virtual type. you can search for it further in di.xml files.